# Is there a way to get your JQuery validation to populate onto the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For one of my classes we're using JQuery validation. I'm trying to get the answers to populate next to the corresponding text on the bottom that's listed (name, age, date,etc..) on the document below after the user inputs the info in the text box.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#input").validate();

     $("#input").submit(function(e) {

         e.preventDefault(); //Prevents from submitting (which is the default action)


          if (!$("#input").valid()) {

                return false;

           } else {
                $("#result").append($("#name").val() + "<br>" + "Your name is");
           }



        });
});

  </script>
  <body>

    <p><b>Fill out all the fields below and click submit</b></p>


        <div>
            <label for="name" class="label">Enter your name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" title="Please enter your name"> </div><br>
        <div>
            <label for="thedate" class="label">Enter today's date</label>
            <input type="text" name="thedate" id="thedate" class="required date"></div><br>
        <div>
            <label for="theage" class="label">Enter your age</label>
            <input type="text" name="theage" id="theage" class="required digits"></div><br>
        <div>
            <label for="theurl" class="label">Enter your web site</label>
            <input type="text" name="theurl" id="theurl" class="required url"></div><br>
        <div>
            <label for="theemail" class="label">Enter your email</label>
            <input type="text" name="theemail" id="theemail" class="required email"></div><br>

        <div>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' name="submit" id='submitme'></div><br>

    </form>
    <p id="result"></p>

    <p><b>Name:</b></p><br>

    <p><b>Date: </b></p><br>

    <p><b>Age:</b> </p><br>

    <p><b>Website: </b></p><br>

    <p><b>Email:</b></p><br>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: for some reason stack is not letting me post my code for what I have . But something like the link and have the answers populate next to the corresponding text below i.e

Name:

Age:

Email:

Comment: try jsfiddle.net

Comment: Okay, hopefully this works

https://jsfiddle.net/seekay/jsgx018m/4/

Comment: Where is `.valid()` function?

Comment: it's in the if statement